# Can't solve a problem where subquery is needed

Tags: sql, subquery

Here is the problem: Some countries have populations more than three times that of any of their neighbours (in the same continent). Give the countries and continents.

This is how I tried to do it, it is incorrect, the sql probably can't set apart these two populations as belonging to different countries, but I have no idea how to proceed.

My first take on it:

```
SELECT name, continent
FROM world
GROUP BY continent
WHERE (population/3) >= population;
```

This is my second try:

```
select name, continent
from world x
where x.population in (select population from world where 
continent=x.continent and x.population>=(3*population))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is with ALL operator:

```
select t.name, t.continent
from world t
where (t.population / 3) > ALL (
  select population from world 
  where continent = t.continent and name <> t.name 
)
```

The subquery contains all the populations of the countries in the same continent as the country of the row that you want to compare (except that country).
So if `population / 3` of that country is greater than all these populations then that country is selected.
Or similarly:

```
select t.name, t.continent
from world t
where (t.population / 3) > (
  select max(population) from world 
  where continent = t.continent and name <> t.name 
)
```